# Help with a PIVOT

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a view that gives data which looks like this:

```
        Rank        |        Score
        --------------------------
        1           |            1
        2           |          2.5
        3           |            5
        1           |            7
        2           |          2.5
        3           |            8
        1           |            9
        2           |          2.5
        3           |            5
```

What I would like to do is apply a PIVOT so that it appears in a 3x3 matrix. The result is always guaranteed to have 9 rows, with RANK going 123..123..123.

```
       1   |   2   |   3
    ------------------------
       1      2.5      5
       7      2.5      8
       9      2.5      5
```

I've attempted to to use a PIVOT, but have been unsuccessful (the part about the aggregate function always confuses me):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyView
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Rank]) FOR [Rank] IN ([1], [2], [3])
) pvt
```

How can I shape my data into the form that I am looking for (PIVOT or otherwise)?

Sorry if the requirement is a bit odd, I'm working with a piece of reporting software that does what I want it to do, if I can shape my data into that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with your current query but I would alter it slightly to use a subquery and include a `row_number()` to give a distinct value to each `score` in your `rank`.

If you query your data using:

```
select [rank], score,
  row_number() over(partition by [rank] order by [rank]) rn
from yourtable
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dd43/4)

You will get a sequenced number for each `score` inside your `ranks`. This sequence number will then be grouped by in your PIVOT making your full code:

```
select [1], [2], [3]
from
(
  select [rank], score,
    row_number() over(partition by [rank] order by [rank]) rn
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(score)
  for [rank] in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dd43/3). This query gives you a result:

```
| 1 |   2 | 3 |
|---|-----|---|
| 1 | 2.5 | 5 |
| 7 | 2.5 | 8 |
| 9 | 2.5 | 5 |
```